# Диалоговые окна в Javascript и Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Доброго дня. Через Bootstrap сделал вывод диалогового окна.

```
 <div id="myModalBox" class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body">
Сам контент!!! </div></div></div></div>
```

При определённом условии отображаю его:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
  var content = '<audio src="site.com/audio.mp3" autoplay"></audio>';
  $("#myModalBox").modal('show');
 });
```

Каким образом в это диалоговое окно можно передать для отображение содержимое переменной content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//if(){ Условие
var new_html =  '<audio src="site.com/audio.mp3" autoplay"></audio>';
    $("#myModalBox .modal-body").html(new_html);
//}

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModalBox" class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body">
Сам контент!!! </div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content = '<span>One, two, three</span>';
  $('#myModalBox').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find(".modal-body").html(content);
  });
  $("#myModalBox").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myModalBox" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Сам контент!!! </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```